# Redis running on 6379 even the conf file changed to 7000

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, redis

I am installing the redis in a Linux Centos by following steps:

```
mkdir /redis/
cd /redis
wget http://redis.googlecode.com/files/redis-2.6.14.tar.gz
extracted it using tar -xzf redis-2.6.14.tar.gz
make && make install PREFIX=/redis/
Changed the port in redis.conf(/redis/redis.conf) to 7000
Changed the port redis_init_script(/redis/utils/redis_init_script) to 7000
Then issued the command /redis/bin/redis-server
```

Now when I issue the command I see this,

[image]

which says `6379`.

:(

Comment: run `netstat -anp | grep 6379` as well as `netstat -anp | grep 7000`. either of these two commands will show you which port redis is actually listening on.

Comment: then it means you're changing the redis port at a WRONG place. OR may be you did not reload/restart the daemon after changing the port.

Comment: Run `/redis/bin/redis-cli info server | grep conf` and double check the `config_file` value to make sure Redis uses the config file you've edited.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told it which config file to use, so you are starting the server with all defaults. Try instead:

```
/redis/bin/redis-server /redis/redis.conf
```